# Prepare Statement Fails to Insert Two out of Four Variables

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, prepare

[image]I added two new fields to a table. The SQL `insert into` continues to work for the two old fields, but fails to insert any data for the two new fields. The two new fields are `$authorflag` and `$artistflag`. These two fields are supposed to be `boolean` variables.

I have experimented by changing these variables from `integer` to `string`, changing their position, and even re-creating the table so that all four fields are new. Despite these tweaks, only the two old variables are actually inserted into the table. The new variables show-up as `null`.

```
$authorflag='NNNNNNNN';
$artistflag=0;
login();
$stmt=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tblAuthorList (AuthorLast,AuthorFirst,AuthorFlag,ArtistFlag) Values(?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sssi', $lastname,$firstname,$authorflag,$artistflag);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute();)` < is that `)` really part of your code? Check for errors on the query also and use error reporting; variables and its origins are unknown. Should post db schema also. and `login()` what that does. Question's unclear. I can't help you here with what you posted.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the new script to the server? Try adding an `echo` statement to see if it's being executed.

Comment: If $authorflag is supposed to be boolean, why do you have NNNNN set as the variable value? And are those fields defined as boolean? Tinyint? What?

Comment: `NNNNNN` will be treated as `0` if you store it into an integer column. `BOOLEAN` is another name for `TINYINT(1)`

Comment: Fred -ii - Good catch. It was a mistake, corrected it, Made no difference in the execution of the program.

Comment: junkfoodjunkie - Yes it is supposed to be a boolean, but I have been revising the data type to see if it would work in a different configuration, which is why it is currently a string. The theory being that my other variables are strings, so maybe converting the variable temporarily to a string would allow it work. It didn't.

Comment: Barmar - The field has been temporarily set to string. Just trying to get something to work.

Comment: Barmar - Four variables are being sent to the server at one-time. Two of them are added to the table, but two are not.

Comment: echo '<pre>', var_dump( $conn, $stmt ), '</pre>'; maybe it can give you some information. As for the 2 variables why don't you double cast them to boolean and then to integer? `$authorflag = (int) (bool) $authorflag;` this way you can be sure that it's and integer. Also output your variables and check there content/type as well. You will need to post your table structure`SHOW CREATE TABLE tblAuthorList` as well if you expect some precise anwears.

Comment: Mujnoi Gyula Tamas - Table Structure uploaded as requested.

Comment: might be a silly question but I'll ask it anyway: you are including `$lastname,$firstname` as part of the new query, right? other than that, I don't know why it's failing

Comment: ^ so? was it a silly question or not? I stared at this thread for 10 mins. now but seen no response.

Comment: – Fred -ii- Yup. Yes it's part of the query. Good question to ask. Usually this type of failure points to something obscure - one of which your already noticed. I even tried an "old-style" MySQL insert, and it failed in the same manner. My wifes says hang-it-up for the night. (Sorry about the time delay. Called away for a while.)

Comment: Yeah, your wife's right. You'll see that on a fresh head with a good night's sleep, it may very well come to you. Let's only hope it's not during the wee hours of the night; get some sleep. I'll try and check back here again tomorrow and maybe.... setup a db on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. The code was correct. The problem was accidentally cross-linking two forms. I have two versions of my database one for production and one for testing. I had combined two tables into one (on both versions) and was correspondingly modifying the associated forms.

Thank you for providing feedback. Getting the thoughts of others is very useful. Happy New Year.

```
$authorflag=1;
$artistflag=0;
login();
$stmt=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO tblAuthorList (AuthorLast,AuthorFirst,AuthorFlag,ArtistFlag) Values(?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $lastname,$firstname,$authorflag,$artistflag);
$stmt->execute();
```